# limiting expansion in marks

Tags: expansion

I'm trying to pass something complex (e.g. `tabular`) to output procedure through `marks`.  Is there any natural way to protect from expansion everything that should be protected (presumably because of not-long definitions)?

Example that does not work without `\noexpand`'s

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mdwtab}
\begin{document}

\leavevmode

\markright{\noexpand\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}<{\noexpand\centering}|}\noexpand\hlx{hv} Row 1 \\ Row 2\\\noexpand\hlx{vh}\noexpand\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\markright{\unexpanded{...whatever...}}`